# How do I change my URL on click in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, onclick, react-router-dom, apollo-client, use-state

The below code adds a next button to get the next 20 items from my backend, on clicking the button the data changes and I get my next 20 items, but the url does not change.

```
function PokemonList() {
const classes = useStyles();
let [pageNum, setPageNum] = useState(0);


  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(pokemonList, { variables: { pageNum: pageNum } });
 
  
  function handleClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    setPageNum(parseInt(pageNum)+1)
    }
  if(error) {
    return <h1> error</h1>;
   }
   
   if(loading) {
    return <h1> loading</h1>;
   }
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.pokemonList.map((data) => (
        
    <Card className={classes.card} variant='outlined'>
                <CardHeader className={classes.titleHead} title={data.id} />
                <CardMedia
                    className={classes.media}
                    component='img'
                    image={data.url}
                    title='image'
                />

                <CardContent>
                    <Typography variant='body2' color='textSecondary' component='span'>
                        <p>{data.name}</p>

                        
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br></br>

      

                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Card>
        
      ))}
<Link onClick={handleClick} className='characterlink2' to={`/pokemon/page/${parseInt(pageNum)+1}`}>
<button>

                        Next
                        </button>
                    </Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PokemonList;
```

How can I fix this? I am not sure that the "to" and "onClick" work together. How do I change the url along with the data?

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` in the click handler prevents the default navigation action from occurring. What do you want the "source of truth" to be for the page? The "pageNum" of the URL or the `pageNum` local state variable. Seems you should use one or the other and let the `useQuery` hook pick up on the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

`e.preventDefault();` in the click handler prevents the default navigation action from occurring.

## Solution

I don't see any reason for this action to be prevented, so I suggest removing this call to prevent the default action.

```
function handleClick(e){
  setPageNum(page => page + 1);
}
```

### Preferred solution

Assuming you've a route with `path="/pokemon/page/:page"` you should use the `useParams` hook and "sniff" the current page. This completely eliminates the need to synchronize the URL path and local React state, there's only one source of truth, the URL path.

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

function PokemonList() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { page } = useParams();

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(
    pokemonList,
    { variables: { pageNum: page } },
  );

  if (error) {
    return <h1>error</h1>;
  }
   
  if (loading) {
    return <h1>loading</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.pokemonList.map((data) => (
        ...
      ))}
      <Link
        className='characterlink2'
        to={`/pokemon/page/${Number(page) + 1}`}
      >
        <button type="button">Next</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```